# Configure GCC to display error for not used variables

Tags: gcc

I need to configure GCC in Ubuntu to display error for not used variables in my code in C and C++?

I'm used Ubuntu 14.04, but not idea for start this configuration!!!

Comment: Just use `-Wall` to display warnings; try avoiding using `-Werror` imho.

Comment: Please try to find answers in your tools documentation before asking at Stack Overflow. Also a simple [google search](https://www.google.de/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=c%2B%2B+gcc+error+unused+variable) should have you gotten on track. Even if most people ask for the opposite.

Answer (score 6):

You can make use of the `-Wunused-variable` option with `gcc` to produce the warning, and `-Werror` to make the warnings as errors.

FWIW, adding `-Wall` implies adding `-Wunused` which in turn implies `-Wunused-variable`. See the [online gcc manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options) for more info on this.

Comment: Note that you can also turn just one particular warning into an error, such as `-Werror=unused-variable`

Comment: @nos Yes, absolutely.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `-Wall` or to only enable unused `-Wunused`. This will give warnings...

If you want to stop compiling when a warning occurs, use  `-Werror`

For more information, look in the official documentation:

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html